# Spot revert tx root cause in empty function call with struct as a parameter

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

I am debugging one interesting issue.

I have a [contract](https://github.com/Gelassen/swap/blob/feature/blockchain-integration/blockchain/contracts/SwapChainV2.sol).
I have [a test coverage](https://github.com/Gelassen/swap/blob/feature/blockchain-integration/blockchain/contracts/SwapChainV2.sol) for this contract.
I have a private locally deployed chain for quick prototyping where [this script](https://github.com/Gelassen/swap/blob/feature/blockchain-integration/blockchain/start_nodes.sh) partly automate startup of nodes.

I have a mobile client to operate with the chain. [(WIP commit)](https://github.com/Gelassen/swap/blob/feature/blockchain-integration/blockchain/contracts/SwapChainV2.sol)

The issue I have now is:

```
Get an error on approve swap call
12-19 05:08:03.499  2591  2591 E TAG     : org.web3j.protocol.exceptions.TransactionException: Transaction 0x4586e05a12f4fcb03b9869a11909392674c5c8b92659dff84ca249071414cb1e has failed with status: 0x0. Gas used: 24002. Revert reason: 'execution reverted'
```

([Ref in source code](https://github.com/Gelassen/swap/blob/eaea06cbdf9c5895650af78d2ddce9aeb55807de/blockchain/contracts/SwapChainV2.sol#L93) on the function signature)

Step-by-step limiting functionality of the `approveSwap(Match memory obj)` method to the pure signature even without applied modifiers I still get this revert issue. Once again - I commented out everything in this function including modifiers and still get my tx reverted.

This brings me to the thought this is an issue with my parameter I pass to the function. That's where I need your help.

(I have [similar scenario](https://github.com/Gelassen/swap/blob/eaea06cbdf9c5895650af78d2ddce9aeb55807de/blockchain/contracts/SwapValue.sol#L52) where I pass a custom struct as a parameter to solidity function call from kotlin android code and this scenario is successful)

Comment: A one community member already pointed out on ```external``` visibility\access modifier could be an issue. It had been changed to ```public```, but reverted tx issue still remains.

Comment: Also ```Match``` parameter should be a ```calldata``` memory represented. Fixed.

Comment: The latest point is a necessity to update binary code in Java\Kotlin wrappers after each change in solidity code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the member field of the struct I passed from kotlin\java code.

Solidity uses its own data types and java types should be cast to them. I knew it and I did it, but for address type I used `Utf8String` instead of `Address`. When I fixed it I was able to overcome this tx revert issue.

Next there were some others pitfalls despite on full test coverage from js side. However this is an another question.